# scapy "ls" function will not show field names properly

Tags: python, scapy

Scapy ls(ARP) function does not show proper field descriptions
pdst is showing a field description MutipleTypeField when used in both scapy terminal and in pycharm

Tried to uninstall/reinstall.  I even used it on a fresh install of both Mint and Kali Linux. still shows the same way

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import scapy.all as scapy

def scan(ip):
 arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
 print(arp_request.summary())
 scapy.ls(scapy.ARP())

scan("10.0.2.0/24")
```

output shows `'ARP who has Net('10.0.2.0/24') says 192.168.1.4'`
just as it should
It appears that something did not install correctly to get the ls functions to properly show the field descriptions properly.

Sorry about the confusion.  I was a bit confused about how to enter the code on the web page.

When I run **ls(ARP)** in the scapy terminal I get the list of options the **ARP** function can use.

It gives me the options but does not give me the option name.

Option **hwdst**  shows field name as  MutipleTypeField
Option **pdst** shows field name as    MutipleTypeField

**hwsrc** returns the MAC address in the 3rd column but it shows the field name of MutipleTypeField in the 2nd column.

In pycharm when I run "**scapy.ls(scapy.ARP())**" it shows the same thing.
It is hard to learn to use a function when you can't see what the options are.

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: pdst       : MultipleTypeField                   = (None)

Comment: Why does it appear that something isn't installed correctly?

Comment: Hi Brat, could you reformat your code properly so that we can read it? I cannot even try to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1:  git clone https://github.com/secdev/scapy.git
Step 2:  cd scapy
step 3:  python3
step 4:  import scapy.all as scapy
step 5:  scapy.ls(scapy.ARP)

That should work!

Comment: I think working in a temporary shell in the scapy source tree is not an appropirate solution to this question.